# left/ right hand side limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I want to calculate the left and right handside limit at $0$ for these functions:

$$\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+6x^4}}$$

$$\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+6x^4}}$$

So plotting the functions would make it very clear, why the one sided limits are different for the first one and the same for the second one.

However what I do not understand how to show that the left and right hand side are $-2$ resp. $+2$ for the first function.

So for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+6x^4}}$ I know that the nominator is positive, and also the denominator of course. However how to show that the limit is $2$? Is this done with L'Hospital? I tried it with L'hospital and got a more complicated expression

and also for $\frac{2x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+6x^4}}$, since we have a square in the nominator, the left hand side and the right hand side will be the same. But what I do not understand is why the limit here becomes zero, and in the other one $+-2$? Is it because x is in a higher degree in the nominator? could someone maybe show me few steps?

Comment: As a side note, it would also be very interesting to replace the $x^2$ in the square root with an $x$. Don't go to DESMOS immediately. Try to work it out analytically, in part using Heropups approach.

Comment: Thanks, great idea, will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x) = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+6x^4}} = \frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+6x^2}},$$ since $x^2 \ge 0$ for all real $x$.  Then since $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, we get $$f(x) = \frac{2 g(x)}{\sqrt{1+6x^2}},$$ where we will take $$g(x) = \frac{|x|}{x} = \begin{cases}1, & x > 0 \\ \text{undefined}, & x = 0 \\ -1, & x < 0. \end{cases}$$  This makes the limiting behavior from either side readily apparent.

There is nothing magical about $g$.  The only thing to understand here is that when considering any particular one-sided limit, $g$ does not change value.  For instance, evaluation of $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x)$$ has $x < 0$ for all such $x$, thus $g(x) = -1$ and $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{2}{\sqrt{1 + 6x^2}}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! Perfectly explained